# Updating the rows returned by a reference cursor in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, cursor

I have a question regarding reference cursors and updating the rows they contain before returning their contents.
Specifically:

let's say that I have a table "People" with the following entries:

```
Id FirstName   LastName     Status
 3  John        struth      pending
 4  Mark        roberts     pending
 1  George      jobs        pending
 2  George      Einstein    working
```

Where Id is the primary key.

and I have an oracle pl/sql procedure that looks like this:

```
PROCEDURE p_get_2_pending_people(p_result OUT REF CURSOR)
BEGIN

OPEN p_result FOR
SELECT * from PEOPLE p
WHERE p.Status = 'pending'
AND rownum <=2;

END p_get_2_pending_people;
```

This will return to me 2 random rows out of the 3 that are available.
However I also want to mark those 2 rows as working at the same time.
I am wondering how can I do that. If I first mark them as working and
then try to return them the cursor won't return anything. If I first
fetch them with the cursor and then I write the same thing to update
them I am not guaranteed that the same 2 rows will be brought back
(out of the 3 available pending rows). Finally if I update the contents
of the cursor then the cursor will be empty when my procedure returns 
the result to the caller.

Thanks

Edit: I added a primary key for the table

Comment: Is there a unique key on that table?

Comment: Yes, just added that in the example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This example does the update first, and return the affected rows afterwards. If you don't have a COMMIT in the procedure, the rows will be locked of course.

The `CARDINALITY`-hint should produce a better execution plan, avoiding a full-table-scan.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE t_ids AS TABLE OF NUMBER(12);
```

```
PROCEDURE p_get_2_pending_people(p_result OUT SYS_REFCURSOR) AS
  ids     t_ids;
BEGIN
  UPDATE people
     SET status = 'pending'
   WHERE ROWNUM <= 2
   RETURNING id
   BULK COLLECT INTO ids;

  OPEN p_result FOR
  SELECT *
    FROM PEOPLE p
   WHERE p.id IN (SELECT /*+ CARDINALITY(t 2) */ COLUMN_VALUE FROM TABLE(ids) t);
END p_get_2_pending_people;
```

Comment: `WHERE p.id IN ( SELECT /*+ CARDINALITY(t 2) */ COLUMN_VALUE FROM TABLE(ids) )` you can write shorter as `WHERE p.id MEMBER OF ids`

Comment: wonderful solution thank you. I'll give it a try in a bit For the sake of completeness, what would you suggest if there wasn't a primary key?

Comment: @Wernfried: That's right, but how would you avoid the full-table-scan with this solution? My solution takes 0.5ms with 500.000 records, while yours took 300ms. Is there another hint I could provide?

Comment: @sakiskaliakoudas: In that case I'd create one ;)

Comment: @sakiskaliakoudas In case if no primary key in a table you can return [`rowid`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/pseudocolumns008.htm) pseudocolumn instead of `id`. Also, this variant eliminates full table scan.

Comment: Maybe `SELECT /*+ CARDINALITY(ids 2) */ * FROM PEOPLE p WHERE p.id MEMBER OF ids`, but I don't know.

Comment: @PeterLang 2 tiny questions for you: a) what does "t" stand for in that hint. b) If my number is not 2 but a parameter passed in the function can I use it in the hint? like /*+ CARDINALITY(t p_count) */

Comment: @sakiskaliakoudas: Fixed my answer, the alias `t` was missing. You cannot use a variable in the hint, but the number does not need to be exact. If you do not provide the hint, the optimizer expects the size of the collection to be your block size (usually 4096 or 8192). See http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:5368262800346952525